# Model for complex form data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to build server model to be parsed from folowwing form data with default ASP.NET MVC model binder:

```
page:1
pageSize:10
filter[filters][0][field]:ApplicantName
filter[filters][0][operator]:eq
filter[filters][0][value]:e
filter[filters][1][field]:ApplicantName
filter[filters][1][operator]:eq
filter[filters][1][value]:d
filter[filters][2][field]:FamilySize
filter[filters][2][operator]:eq
filter[filters][2][value]:2
filter[filters][3][logic]:or
filter[filters][3][filters][0][field]:WaitList
filter[filters][3][filters][0][operator]:eq
filter[filters][3][filters][0][value]:3
filter[filters][3][filters][1][field]:WaitList
filter[filters][3][filters][1][operator]:doesnotcontain
filter[filters][3][filters][1][value]:3
```

It's ok with `page` and `pageSize` but can't do the same for filters. Tried the following:

```
public class DataSourceRequest
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public DataSourceFilter Filter { get; set; }
}

public class DataSourceFilter
{
    public IEnumerable<DataSourceFilter> Filters { get; set; }
    public string Logic { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

But had no success. Root `Filter` is not null but there is no any nested data.

Comment: Is correct this line? `public IEnumerable<DataSourceFilter> Filters { get; set; }`

Comment: Please post your controller and View... I suspect that the problem is in your view.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to build server model to be parsed from folowwing form data
>   with default ASP.NET MVC model binder:

You can't. The default model binder doesn't understand nor supports this syntax. Please read the [`following article`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) to better understand the supported wire format that the default model binder works with.

And then fix your request in order to comply with the expected format:

```
page                                   1
pageSize                               10
filter.filters[0].field                ApplicantName
filter.filters[0].operator             eq
filter.filters[0].value                e
filter.filters[1].field                ApplicantName
filter.filters[1].operator             eq
filter.filters[1].value                d
filter.filters[2].field                FamilySize
filter.filters[2].operator             eq
filter.filters[2].value                2
filter.filters[3].logic                or
filter.filters[3].filters[0].field     WaitList
filter.filters[3].filters[0].operator  eq
filter.filters[3].filters[0].value     3
filter.filters[3].filters[1].field     WaitList
filter.filters[3].filters[1].operator  doesnotcontain
filter.filters[3].filters[1].value     3
```

And if for some reason you cannot modify the request format you will have to write a custom model binder and parse the values manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this approach to handle the list of filters:

[Editing variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

This will be posting to server following the format that is understandable to the model binder.

It will also help you if you remove and add filters... since the index will became with "holes" in the secuence (this is not supported by the default model binder)... and this approach is more robust in that aspect not relying in the integers secuence.